# Post on native php (without framework) Into Code Igniter using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to post data on my HTML code to CI with Ajax. But I got no response?

**Here is my JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#simpan").click(function(){
    nama_pelanggan = $("#nama_pelanggan").val();
    telp = $("#telp").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.100.100/booking_dev/booking/addBookingViaWeb/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            "nama_pelanggan":nama_pelanggan,
            "telp":telp,
        },
        success: function(res) {
            if (res){
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    });     
});
});
```

**And here is my form**

```
<form>
Nama Pelanggan <br> 
<input type="text" name="nama_pelanggan" id="nama_pelanggan"><br>
Telepon<br>
<input type="text" name="telp" id="telp"><br>
<input type="button" name="simpan" id="submit" value="Simpan">
</form>
```

and here is my contoller function code

```
public function addBookingViaWeb(){
    $data = array(
        'nama_pelanggan' => $this->input->post('nama_pelanggan'),
        'telp'=>$this->input->post('telp')
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**Here is my post param**

[image: Here my postparam]

**But I got no response**

[image: response param]

any idea?

Comment: Try using `crossDomain :true` in ajax.... if you are performing a cross domain exchange.... And `alert(msg)` is not gonna give you anything instead of error... :)

Comment: Have tried to change this `alert(msg);` to `alert(res);` ? What about `alert(res.responseText);` ?

Comment: try `echo json_encode($data);exit;`

Comment: are you sure `$data` to be a valid array?If you can run this code in non ajax way try `print_r($data)`

Comment: still no response :(

Comment: @newbie Please hit the URL 'http://192.168.100.100/booking_dev/booking/addBookingViaWeb/' directly from the address bar of the browser.

Comment: @techie_28 it show `{"nama_pelanggan":null,"telp":null}`

Comment: @newbie it by removing `dataType:json` attribute all together..you should see something in response & put a `echo print_r($this->input->post);` & `echo print_r($_REQUEST);exit;` before `json_encode`

Comment: @newbie it is possible your `$this->input->post` works if form is posted normally & via ajax please try to replace them with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @techie_28 thank for your advice, I just add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` on my function controller

Comment: First off make sure you're receiving it on the backend at all. `error_log($data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my problem from my friend xD
just add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` on controller function

Thank you for helping answer my problem.

Comment: nobody knew here that you were doing a  cross domain call.. :)

Answer (score 0):

add method in from if you use post then

```
<form method="post"  action ="" >
```

Comment: hi, I need to post the data with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see is in your ajax submission code. Change

```
$("#simpan").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
```

Notice that I added the event parameter. You now need to prevent the default submission behavior. On the first line of your click method add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Now I'm assuming that your url endpoint `http://192.168.100.100/booking_dev/booking/addBookingViaWeb/` can handle POST requests. Usually this is done with something like PHP or Ruby on Rails. If I was doing this in PHP I would write something like the following:

```
<?php
    $arg1 = $_POST["nama_pelanggan"];
    $arg2 = $_POST["telp"];

    // do something with the arguments

    $response = array("a" => $a, "b" => $b);
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I personally don't know anything about handling POST requests with js (as a backend) but what I've given you should get the data over there correctly.

Comment: I've declare it on my controller function

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery form `serialize()` to declare which data you want to post. It automatically put your form input into ajax data. Example :

first set ID to your form tag

```
<form id="form">
```

then

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url : 'http://192.168.100.100/booking_dev/booking/addBookingViaWeb/',
    data:$('#form').serialize(),
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Dude take a look at his onclick method. The ajax method is never even fired.

Comment: @fruitoftheloins it does..you can see the status code 200 there.

Comment: sorry I copied the wrong code for submit id xD, but it still give no response when I add serialize() :(

Comment: @techie_28 any Idea? Cause the code is normal if I put the code inside CI

Comment: @newbie I have another solution , but it little bit native. You can try using `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`. Then use `$data->nama_pelanggan` to get nama_pelanggan value. I hope it will works